I am trying import a folder into a jupyter notebook for preprocessing but having some problem assessing the path of the files in the folder
I want to extract the files in a folder and list out the names of the files in the folder, put them in a dataframe and list out all the contents in a single dataframe.
I used the below code:
# Import the os module
    import os

# Define the path to the file
    file_path = "C:/Users/844444/OneDrive - 
    hull.ac.uk/T3\Dataset/Crystal Clean-Brain Tumors 
    MRI Dataset" # folder path

# list all the files in the folder
    files = os.listdir("C:/Users/844444/OneDrive - 
    hull.ac.uk/T3\Dataset/Crystal Clean-Brain Tumors 
    MRI Dataset")

    print(files)

I got the below error message
<>:5: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\D'
<>:8: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\D'
<>:5: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\D'
<>:8: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\D' C:\Users\844444\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_2768\3354836572.py:5: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\D'
file_path = "C:/Users/879304/OneDrive - 
hull.ac.uk/T3\Dataset/Crystal Clean-Brain Tumors 
MRI Dataset" # folder path C:\Users\844444\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_2768\3354836572.py:8: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\D'
files = os.listdir("C:/Users/879304/OneDrive - 
hull.ac.uk/T3\Dataset/Crystal Clean-Brain Tumors 
MRI Dataset")


try adding an 'r' before your path string or replace backslashes ('') with forward slashes ('/') or escaping the backslashes ('\')

Your filepath looks not correct. You have slashes and backslashes in in your path. And based on your example code remove the line break (write the filepath in one line, or format it as multiline string with """My/File/Path"""). And something different: you define your path as file_path variable, but don´t use it in your os.listdir()

This is happening because the characters \D in the string (in \Dataset) are interpreted as an escape sequence (python documentation on escape sequences) — like "\n" that means a new line for example.
To avoid this behaviour, you can either replace the backslash \ with two backslashes \\ (which is the escape sequence for a single backslash), or add an r in front of the string as follows:
    file_path = r"C:/Users/844444/OneDrive - 
    hull.ac.uk/T3\Dataset/Crystal Clean-Brain Tumors 
    MRI Dataset" # folder path

# list all the files in the folder
    files = os.listdir(r"C:/Users/844444/OneDrive - 
    hull.ac.uk/T3\Dataset/Crystal Clean-Brain Tumors 
    MRI Dataset")

    print(files)

this tells Python to avoid interpreting escape sequences
